# How to check normal distribution for categorical data in Excel?

Tags: normal-distribution, categorical-data, contingency-tables, excel

I am currently exploring whether the presence of psychologists on wards has an impact on the number of incidents that occurs on the ward.

Independent variable would be Psychologist Presence (Yes or No)
Dependent variable would be Incidents (Yes or No). Also if there are incidents I have the number of incidents.

I am doing the analysis on Excel. My question is how do I check if the data are normally distributed via Excel? I have tried histograms and bar charts but I seem to be doing something wrong because it's comes blank, maybe because the IV and DV are categorical?

Also, would I be doing a Chi-square test because the IV and DV are categorical.
And do a t-test between the IV: Psychologist Presence (Yes or No), and number of incidents?

Comment: A categorical variable cannot have a normal distribution. Have you tried changing your variable to number of incidents, replacing the 'No' with a '0'?

Comment: It sounds like a test for binomial proportions is what you are after, not a t-test. See this: https://www.spss-tutorials.com/binomial-test/

Comment: You can present your data as a contingency table. Maybe show us that table?